# self-similar iff infinitely self-similar

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A topological space $X$ is

- *self-similar* if there is a proper subspace $Y \subsetneq X$ such that $Y \simeq X$.
- *infinitely self-similar* if there is a sequence of subspaces $(X_k)_{k \geq 0}$ such that $$X=X_0 \supsetneq X_1 \supsetneq X_2 \supsetneq \dots \hspace{1em} \text{and} \hspace{1em} X_i \simeq X \ \forall \ i \geq 0.$$

Indeed, *infinitely self-similar* $\Rightarrow$ *self-similar* is true. But, what about the other implication? I mean, *self-similar* $\Rightarrow$ *infinitely self-similar* is true? I suspect no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your suspicion is incorrect. Assume that $X$ is a "self-similar'' topological space.. So there is a proper subspace $Y$ of $X$ homeomorphic to $X$ say via a homeomorphism $f : Y \to X$. The sequence of subspaces $X_i$ of $X$ defined by:

$$
\begin{align*}
X_0 &= X \\
X_{i+1} &= f^{-1}[X_i]
\end{align*}
$$

then shows that $X$ is "infinitely self-similar".